# Bottom sheet over map content, similar to google maps UI, in React Native

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet, react-native-flexbox

I am trying to implement a UI layout similar to google maps "explore" on Android, (see [gif](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Offline-Maps-setup-1.gif)) in React Native.

In my UI design I have app navigation tabs at the bottom of the screen, with a full page map background, overlaid with a "bottom sheet" coming from above the tabs, and a search box component at the top.  See UI sketch below.

[image: UI Design]

I have found various react-native ui components which look useful, but I can't figure out the styling to arrange them in the layout I want.

Several of the bottomsheet components I'm looking at, for example, rn-bottom-drawer show gifs similar to what I'm trying to create, e.g [this animation](https://github.com/jacklein/rn-bottom-drawer/blob/master/demo.gif), but I can't find an actual code example of how that UI was created.  For example, the same library [example](https://github.com/jacklein/rn-bottom-drawer/blob/master/example/example.js) just shows the bottom drawer over an empty screen.

What combination of wrapping elements and styles would allow me to create the layout described?  I come from a XAML background and this kind of layout is very easy to create, but I can't get my head around how to do it in react native.

Comment: does anyone have good library reference? I am looking for the same

Answer (score 1):

It is halfway possible with the component "react-native-swipe-up-down".
The swipe up above the App works, but it is really buggy. Had the same problem as you and couldn't find anything better than swipe-up-down til today.

Comment: Did you check this?
https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/

Comment: this is one best library bottom sheet from gorhom